# Windows sockets: How to immediately detect TCP RST on nonblocking connect()?

Tags: windows, select, tcp, winsock, winsock2

Our software ([Nmap port scanner](https://nmap.org)) needs to quickly determine the status of a non-blocking TCP socket `connect()`. We use [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) to monitor a lot of sockets, and Windows is good at notifying us when one succeeds. But if the port is closed and the target sends a TCP RST, Windows will keep trying a few times before notifying the `exceptfds`, and the socket error is `WSAECONNREFUSED` as expected. Our application has its own timeout, though, and will usually mark the connection as timed-out before Windows gives up. We want to get as close as possible to the behavior of Linux, which is to notify with `ECONNREFUSED` immediately upon receipt of the first RST.

We have tried using the [`TCP_MAXRT` socket option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-tcp-socket-options), and this works to get `select()` to signal us right away, but the result (for closed ports) is always `WSAETIMEDOUT`, which makes it impossible to distinguish closed (RST) from filtered/firewalled (network timeout), which puts us back at the original problem. Determining this distinction is a core feature of our application.

So what is the best way on Windows to find out if a non-blocking socket `connect()` has received a connection reset?

EDITED TO ADD: A core problem here is this line from Microsoft's documentation on the `SO_ERROR` socket option: "This per-socket error code is not always immediately set." If it were immediately set, we could check for it prior to the connect timeout.

Comment: You may be out of luck here. I believe the underlying problem to be this. BSD-derived TCPs drop incoming SYNs if the backlog queue is full, which is indistinguishable at the client from host or network down, so `connect()` retries, which is plausible: if `connect()` gets an RST it means no listening socket, so it returns immediately. Windows on the other hand issues an RST if the backlog queue is full, so the client can't distinguish that condition from no listening socket, so it retries on both, which is pontless on no listening socket. I don't know whether you can fix this.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne That's really helpful information, though, thanks!